# Dataset.from_generator: TypeError: `generator` must be callable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently using a generator to produce my training and validation datasets using `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`. I have a class method that takes care of this for me:

```
def build_dataset(self, batch_size=16, shuffle=16, validation=None):
    
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(import_images(validation=validation), (tf.float32, tf.float32))
    self.train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(shuffle).repeat(-1).batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
    
    if validation is not None:
        val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(import_images(validation=validation), (tf.float32, tf.float32))
        self.val_dataset = val_dataset.repeat(1).batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
```

The problem is passing in `(validation=validation)` to my `import_images` generator creates the generator object which Tensorflow doesn't want, and it gives me the error:

```
TypeError: `generator` must be callable.
```

Because I have to pass in `validation` to tell my generator to produce a separate training and validation version, I am required to create two versions of the same generator. It also doesn't allow me to pass in other arguments to control the percentage of training and validation examples - meaning the generator has to be static. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered a similar problem, but I'm a beginner so not sure if this will help.

Try add a **call** function in your class.

Below are the original class which raise `` TypeError: `generator` must be callable. ``

```py
class DataGen:
  def __init__(self, files, data_path):
    self.i = 0
    self.files=files
    self.data_path=data_path
  
  def __load__(self, files_name):
    data_path = os.path.join(self.data_path, files_name)
    arr_img, arr_mask = load_patch(data_path)
    return arr_img, arr_mask

  def getitem(self, index):
    _img, _mask = self.__load__(self.files[index])
    return _img, _mask

  def __iter__(self):
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    if self.i < len(self.files):
      img_arr, mask_arr = self.getitem(self.i)
      self.i += 1
    else:
      raise StopIteration()
    return img_arr, mask_arr
```

Then I revised the code as below and it worked for me.

```py
class DataGen:
  def __init__(self, files, data_path):
    self.i = 0
    self.files=files
    self.data_path=data_path
  
  def __load__(self, files_name):
    data_path = os.path.join(self.data_path, files_name)
    arr_img, arr_mask = load_patch(data_path)
    return arr_img, arr_mask

  def getitem(self, index):
    _img, _mask = self.__load__(self.files[index])
    return _img, _mask

  def __iter__(self):
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    if self.i < len(self.files):
      img_arr, mask_arr = self.getitem(self.i)
      self.i += 1
    else:
      raise StopIteration()
    return img_arr, mask_arr
  
  def __call__(self):
    self.i = 0
    return self
```